# See close votes on my own question

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions

Are users supposed to be able to see how many "close" votes **their own** question has?  I know you have to have a certain amount of rep to close a question in general, but on Stack Overflow's meta, I can see if someone is voting to close my own question, but not on English.StackExchange.

Are the sites just set up differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the [privileges page](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/view-close-votes), at 250 reputation you earn the ability to view close votes on your own questions. You also gain the ability to vote on them for close and reopening.

Here you have under 250. On Meta, you have greater than 250.